# null power element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Show that there is $x\in A$ such that $x^2=0$.

I think in abelian C*-algebra $x^2=0$ if and only if $x=0$(because these elements are continuous functions) Also in certain C*-algebras such as $M_2(\Bbb C)$, I can find this element, but I can not show it in general. Please just give me a hint for that. Thanks.

Comment: In the first line, you presumably want $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @Rasmus: yes. I want $x\neq 0$

Comment: And the Jordan canonical form: $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$. Nilpotent elements are never normal, which is why normal matrices fully diagonalize.

Comment: @T.A.E. : How can I show that this element exists in $A$?

Comment: @niki : My comment was directed at the Abelian case. Are you sure that one will exist? What if you generate a $C^{\star}$ algebra from a quasinilpotent, non-nilpotent operator $N$?